# Force code formatter in IntelliJ to join lines

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to force IntelliJ to reformat the code the way Eclipse does it.
When I set a line width to e.g. 120 chars I would like IDE to join line that were broken up to multiple lines (e.g. because the line width was set to 80 chars).

I want to go from here:

```
int a = 1
    + 2;
```

To here:

```
int a = 1 + 2
```

Is it possible in IntelliJ? I'm looking for the appropriate setting in the formatter but cannot find it. Could someone tell me where I can find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me in intellij 8 if i go to:

```
File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Wrapping -> Binary operations -> set to: 'Wrap if long' or 'Do not wrap'
```

Then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to reformat the code

Answer (score 5):

If your code already contains inappropriate line breaks and you want the formatter to remove them during the reformat,

```
File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Wrapping and Braces -> 
Keep When Formatting -> Line Breaks -> Untick
```

(at least on IntelliJ 15 based Editors)

Answer (score 4):

Menu -> Edit -> Join Lines (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

Answer (score 3):

For Intellij 2016.2.x I had to deselect this option in the Settings:[image]

Then go back to your code and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>