# IntelliJ force code formatter to join lines based on wrap settings

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

How can i reformat file(s) in IntelliJ and join all lines that are split.

I know that I can do that individually by selecting lines and "join lines" with `CTRL + SHIFT + J`

Since we changed our code formatting wrap policy recently I want to be able to join lines in all files based on the updated wrap setting. (Settings > Code Style > General > Right margin)

The only thing is that IntelliJ seems happy to split lines based on wrap setting, but will silently deny to join lines based on that setting.

Unlike the question [Force code formatter in IntelliJ to join lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867507/force-code-formatter-in-intellij-to-join-lines), I am not satisfied by splitting lines or joining manually (as the accepted answer suggests). I want IntelliJ to join lines automatically.

Bonus question: Which other editors can do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Disable the following code style option - Project Settings - Code Style - Wrapping and Braces - Keep when reformatting - Line breaks

Comment: Thanks! Note to self: The setting has to be UNCHECKED (bad wording in interface, since it is confusing that you uncheck in order for the editor to take action)

Answer (score 2):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15**

- File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Keep when reformatting > **uncheck Line breaks**

  [image: uncheck Line breaks]

  (if you want to have the same setting for another type of file, choose it from Code Style)
- Go to Code > Reformat Code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>).