# PHPStorm expand code that is one line

Tags: phpstorm

I have been trying to figure out how to expand code that is compressed to one line.

Does anyone know how to expand coding that is done this way in phpstorm?

[image]

Comment: `Code | Reformat Code...` ?

Comment: Thanks so much!! I have spent hours trying to figure that out! Please submit as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I know a little late but you can chack here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867507/force-code-formatter-in-intellij-to-join-lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your XML file readable (easy to read) you can use `Code | Reformat Code...`

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/reformatting-source-code.html?search=reformat

Comment: If you need opposite action (reformat code to 1 line, for example for JS bookmarklet), you can use "Join" feature in PhpStorm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/joining-lines-and-literals.html#d1649764e13